# Is "kindly reminder" a correct expression?

Tags: grammar

Can I use the phrase "kindly reminder" to remind of something?
I saw people using it, but it doesn't seem to be grammatically correct.

Comment: You need to give an example of the sentence in which you want to use it, or have heard people using it. _A reminder_ is something that helps you to remember to do something, but 'kindly' is usually an adverb.

Comment: Please provide a full sentence as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using "kindly" as an adjective, rather than an adverb, is correct but may be considered old-fashioned by some. A kindly action is one which is kind, thoughtful, meant helpfully, etc.

> adjective

A kindly person or action is a kind one:

> a kindly old lady

[Kindly (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kindly)

Comment: *A kind old lady* sounds more natural to me than *a kindly old lady*. As Kate Bunting said in a comment to the question, *kindly* is more often used as an adverb. (*Her welcome was kindly given.*) I would think of the use of *kindly* as an adjective (while not wrong) as more archaic. In fact, your Cambridge link does refer to its adjectival use as old-fashioned.

Comment: I fear I am more than a little old-fashioned. After I posted the above answer, my partner asked "What are you humming?" When I answered "Lead, Kindly Light", she just nodded. I don't think 'archaic' and 'old-fashioned' are identical in meaning.